# Why modified request in Express JS is not keeping its value between POST and GET requests?

Tags: node.js, express, http-post, http-get

for a test project I need to login with an user defined only by username, and load new page with that user. 
My code in the tamplate is:

```
        <form action="/login" method="post">
        username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        password: <input type="password" name="password">
        <button type="submit" style="float: right;">Login..</button>
        </form>
```

The Express code in app.js is:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.usersession = { "userId" : "myUser" };
    next();
})
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// development only
  if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
   app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
//routes
app.get('/project', routes.project); 
app.get('/dashboard', routes.dashboard);
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.post('/addProject', routes.addProject); 
app.post('/login', routes.login);
```

and the  /login function:

```
exports.login = function (req, res) {
var query = req.body.username;
Users.
findOne({ 'username' : query }).
exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) res.send('Username not found'); 
   // exports.dashboard();     
    req.usersession = result._id;
});
```

the /dashboard

```
exports.dashboard = function (req, res) {
Project.
find( { "project._addedBy" : req.usersession.userId}).
select("project.projectName project._addedBy").
exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var data = { "rendData" : result };
    res.render('dashboard', data);
});
};
```

When the browser is redirected to /dashboard, it starts with the initial data for req.usersession - myUser.
How could I pass the req.usersession between both pageloads?

Sorry if my terms are not right, but I am new to the web.

Thanks!

Comment: are you guessing "How can I store session between different pages and prevent its data from loss?"

Comment: Actually I know there are many methods, one of which are to expand the request object with custom field, using express middleware, which I am trying to use, but something is not right.

Comment: can you please explain better what's wrong? I haven't understood the problem

Comment: First I call the login and the req.user got the correct value. But after that when calling the dashboard (either with redirect from login or other way), the req.user got again the initial value.

Comment: You set it to the initial value in the first app.use (...), have you tried removing it? After that req.usersession is undefined?

Comment: I set it to empty object, but still the same. After GET it is with default value

Comment: Note that app.use means that every request will do that piece of code, in your case every single request will replace the req.usersession. I suggest you using express-session middleware to store sessions data and cookie-parser to save the session id as a cookie. Let me know if it solves your problem

Comment: I was trying to avoid using sessions or cookies and this approach looks like the simplest one, also I've been told it should work..

Comment: Ok, avoiding sessions or cookies it's possible but you have to do it by yourself as HTTP is stateless. One approach could be using an external storage (redis, memcached, etc) to save user session data. Then you should send a key to the client so for future requests he can tell te server "who is". On each request the server should check this key and retrieve saved data before completing any request. On the client side you could use Local Storage to save the session key and you must send it to the server in each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are mixing the approaches. The middleware app.use function logs in a fake user and it does that for every request. You are then trying to do an actual login by checking the database for the form data. The middleware will override the actual login for every other request. You should pick one or the other - a real login with a db check and a session or a mock login middleware if you don't care to go all the way for this study project...

Comment: Okay than the session it is.. since I plan to add more variables into the req. It was easier than expected :)